# __awaiter is not defined

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm using typescript v 1.8.9 in VSCode, nodejs 5.9.1 i have my file app.ts that has these lines

```
import {XController} from "./XController";

var xContrller=new XController();
xContrller.CallAsyncMethod(some args");
```

and XController is a class having async methode CallAsyncMethod

like this

```
public async CallAsyncMethod(url: string) {
        await this.request.post(url);
}
```

this translates to __awaiter(void,...) in javascript but it crashes saying that __awaiter is not defined ??? any clues why this is happening and how to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: Have you attempted to await `xContrller.CallAsyncMethod(some args");`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `tsconfig.json` is most likely wrong. The following worked just fine:

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es6",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": [
      "node_modules",
      "typings/browser",
      "typings/browser.d.ts"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": true
}
```

`ping.ts`:

```
export async function ping() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        await delay(300);
        console.log("ping");
    }
}

function delay(ms: number) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

`main.ts`:

```
import {ping} from "./ping"

async function main() {
    await ping();
}

main();
```

Comment: First thank you that solved the issue but i suspect there is a bug, because i have the same tsconfig plus "noEmitHelpers" and it looks that this caused the issue is there any explanation (when i remove it it worked) ? thanks

Comment: Ahmed, thanks for pointing out the noEmitHelpers setting issue, this helped me get async-await working in NativeScript 2.5.0!